# how can i see the sawgger documentation of my services?

Tags: java, rest, web, swagger, cxf

I am using Swagger version 2.
I get the result below when i request :

```
 http://localhost:8080/SwaggerProject/jaxrs/MyService/V1/swagger.json

"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
"description": "The Application",
"version": "1.0.0",
"title": "Sample REST Application",
"contact": {
  "name": "users@cxf.apache.org"
},
"license": {
  "name": "Apache 2.0 License",
  "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
}
},
  "basePath": "/SwaggerProject/jaxrs/MyService/V2"
  }
```

My question is how can i see the sawgger documentation of my service(MyService) ?
Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

With that link you request the swagger json configuration. I assume that you are using swagger to document some sort of Rest Web service.

In order to define swagger you need to edit the web xml or Overwrite the Application Config as you may now . So in order to see the full documentation and the sampling as well as the services presentation in a more user friendly way you can define the swagger url and general configuration from the above mentioned .

I have used swagger before but i cant recall/find the default configuration wright now. But,
 a very nice example Configuring Swagger with Spring can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

Another useful link if you are using c# [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/873)

Also you can check [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/559) one too .

An example of Application config using java as lang [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-example-with-application/).
I hope this helped.
Finally my guess for the default index set-up would be something like  http://ip:port/YourServiceName/namespace_if_using_one/swagger/index.html